# Как вычислить ср. значения по всем числовым столбцам набора данных Orange?

Tags: r

Необходимо вычислить и вывести средние значения по всем числовым столбцам набора
данных Orange и описательную статистику по набору данных Orange.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, вы хотите посмотреть на среднее значение возраста и длину колец деревьев из датасета `Orange`. Это можно сделать следующим образом, сгруппировав по номеру дерева:

```
library(tidyverse)

Orange %>%
  group_by(Tree) %>%
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE),
            mean_cir = mean(circumference, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Базовую описательную статистику можно получить, применив функцию `summary` к датасету.

В следующий раз, пожалуйста, уточняйте вопрос: приведите пример данных, образ ожидаемого результата и пр.

Comment: Мне бы тоже хотелось получить больше информации, чтобы выполнить это задание.

Answer (score 0):

```
data(Orange)
sapply(Orange[c(2,3)], mean)
summary(Orange)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В комментарии вы написали: _Мне бы тоже хотелось получить больше информации, чтобы выполнить это задание_, и через 5 минут дали ответ. То есть, всю информацию за это время вы получили. Это так?